# `queue()` function is not found error so Queued actions not firing JS

Tags: javascript, data-visualization

**update**
The browser console shows that `queue` is undefined.

I'm a beginner taking an interest in d3 and data viz. I've modified a boilerplate project by Adil Moujahid found [here](http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2015/01/interactive-data-visualization-d3-dc-python-mongodb/). I'm having problems getting the charts to render on the localhost. The charts.js file is as below. I believe the queue() method isn't firing.

```
queue()
.defer(d3.json, "/nba/utah")
.await(makeGraphs);

function makeGraphs(error, projectsJson, statesJson) {
    var utahProjects = projectsJson;
    var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");
    utahProjects.forEach(function(d) {
        d["Game Date"] = dateFormat.parse(d["Game Date"]);
    });

var ndx = crossfilter(utahProjects);

var gameDateDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d["Game Date"]; });
var teamPtsDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d["Team Pts"]; });
var teamRebDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d["Team Reb"]; });
var teamAstDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d["Team Ast"]; });
var teamFgmDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d["FGM"]; });
var teamFgaDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d["FGA"]; });
var teamMatchupDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d["Matchup"]; });

var all = ndx.groupAll();
var gamesByDate = gameDateDim.group();
var gamesByPts = teamPtsDim.group();

var minDate = gameDateDim.bottom(1)[0]['Game Date'];
var maxDate = gameDateDim.top(1)[0]['Game Date'];
var minPts = teamPtsDim.bottom(1)[0]['Team Pts'];
var maxPts = teamPtsDim.top(1)[0]['Team Pts'];

var timeChart = dc.barChart("#time-chart");
var ptsChart = dc.barChart("#total-pts");

timeChart
.width(600)
.height(160)
.margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50})
.dimension(gameDateDim)
.group(gamesByDate)
.transitionDuration(500)
.x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]))
.elasticY(true)
.xAxisLabel("Year")
.yAxis().ticks(4);

ptsChart
.width(600)
.height(160)
.margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50})
.dimension(dateDim)
.group(gamesByPts)
.transitionDuration(500)
.x(d3.time.scale().domain([minPts, maxPts]))
.elasticY(true)
.xAxisLabel("Year")
.yAxis().ticks(4);

dc.renderAll();
}
```

This is the app.py framework I'm using to build the server:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json
from bson import json_util
from bson.json_util import dumps

app = Flask(__name__)

MONGODB_HOST = 'mongodb://user:password@aws-server.com'
MONGODB_PORT = 27017
DBS_NAME = 'nba'
COLLECTION_NAME = 'Utah Jazz2017-18'
FIELDS = {'Team Pts': True, 'Team Reb': True, 'Team Ast': True, 'FGM': True, 'FGA': True, 'Matchup': True, 'Game Date': True, '_id': False}

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/nba/utah")
def nba_projects():
connection = MongoClient(MONGODB_HOST, MONGODB_PORT)
collection = connection[DBS_NAME][COLLECTION_NAME]
projects = collection.find(projection=FIELDS)
json_projects = []
for project in projects:
    json_projects.append(project)
json_projects = json.dumps(json_projects, default=json_util.default)
connection.close()
return json_projects

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000,debug=True)
```

Please let me know where I've gone astray.

Comment: Where did you create the `queue()` reference. I'm assuming D3-queue? That requires you do use: `d3.queue()` or assign it like `let queue = d3.queue';

Comment: Ok, looked at project. So assuming you've included `queue` from there. So next question, what errors show in the browser dev tools console?

Comment: Yep it is a reference to the d3 queue lib! I've updated the reference but the browser console is still showing a queue is not defined error.

Comment: Please ensure you are loading the the `queue.js` prior to this `charts.js` file in your HTML file.

Comment: by the way, you said _browser console is still showing a queue is not defined error_. That would have been helpful to know from the very beginning - since _that_ is the real issue here.

Comment: Sorry, I've been using the server console to debug instead of the browser window. The queue.js file is loaded before the charts.js file - https://pastebin.com/LpM9GBHD

Comment: ok, lets add a quick test. Right after `queue()`, chain a new `defer()` and alert something like this: `queue().defer(()=>{alert('Ding!');})` You can leave the other `defer()` calls there if you like.

Comment: Wait - does the browser console STILL say that queue is undefined? Or is it that the file is now found (a 404)?

Comment: Queue is now defined, I added a console.log output to check the browser was accessing it. The alert we've deferred isn't showing in the console - regardless of whether or not the other calls are there. We now have a type error - d3.queue is not a function.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me - really appreciate the help.

Comment: Right - you are not using `d3.queue`. That was a bad assumption on my part. Remove the `d3.` so that it is just `queue()`

Comment: We're now back to queue is undefined.

Comment: In the browser developer tools, open the console, type `queue` hit enter. What happens?

Comment: Output is 'queue is not defined'.

Comment: So either the file is not loaded (a 404) or there is an error preventing it from being loaded. Use this reference to help troubleshoot the file problem. Not much more I can do for you from here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference